# Unable to add tables to Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, oracle, crystal-reports, reporting

Background:
I have an old report in which I am trying to add a table and a field. The report works perfectly fine in my web application. (Crystal reports ver. 11.5.9.1076)

After adding a table I get the error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Failed to open connection**

This happens whether I add a table, command, or stored procedure to the report. (Connecting to Oracle database)

Things I've tried:

- Add table (crashes), remove table (works again)
- Click the "Verify database" button in the Database menu
- Set database location and update the newly added table
- Previewing the report seems to work

As for how I'm providing the data:

1. Create and load ReportDocument (VB.net)
2. Populate DataSet
3. Call SetDataSource method with DataSet as param
4. ExportToHttpResponse as PortableDocFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we had to do in order to make this work in our crystal reports: after loading the report, we loop through each of the `DataSourceConnections` in the report and update the connection information.

```
For Each oConnection As IConnectionInfo In oReport.DataSourceConnections
    If fUseIntegratedSecurity Then
        oConnection.SetConnection(sServerName, sDatabaseName, True)
    Else
        oConnection.IntegratedSecurity = False
        oConnection.SetConnection(sServerName, sDatabaseName, sUserLogon, sUserPassword)
    End If
Next
```

The actual connection details are provided elsewhere in our app, so I am just showing placeholders in the code above.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thanks, you saved me hours of more research